# Having trouble with single page design

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to html and css, only just started about a week ago. But I'm having some issues getting the width of my page to fit the screen no matter what monitor I'm viewing the site on. I've tried `background-size: cover;`, `width: 100%;`, etc. I know there's something I'm not thinking of.

Secondly, and this may sound really dumb, is there a way to add page length without content?

Sorry if these are simple questions, I've been searching for the answers for a while now. Below is my code, if anyone has any recommendations that would help for single page design, please let me know!

Thanks!!

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<a name="totop" />
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title> Jack Johnson</title>

  <!-- Import CSS Stylesheets Here -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///C:/users/Jack/desktop/projects/mysitecss.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<body>

<div id="first-page">

  <p class="header">Jack Johnson</p>
  <p class="subheader">Marketing and Design Specialist</p>
  <div id="nav-button">

    <a href="#topage2" class="smoothScroll"><center>Scroll Down</center></a></div>

</div> <!-- End of first page -->



<div id="second-page">
  <a name="topage2" />

  <p class="Quote">I've got a degree in marketing and an aptitude for design.</p>
  <p class="P1">Test text 2.</p>

  <div id="nav-button2">
    <a href="#topage3" class="smoothScroll"><center>Scroll Down</center></a></div>

</div> <!--End of second page-->



<div id="third-page">

  <a name="topage3" />

  <div id="nav-button3">

    <a href="#totop" class="smoothScroll"><center>Go to Top</center></a>

  </div>

</div><!--End of third page-->


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/users/Jack/desktop/projects/smoothscroll.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html {background-color: #ffffff; background-size: cover; size: 100%; overflow-x: hidden;}
body {font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;}
.smoothScroll {font-size: 18px; text-decoration: bold; color: #000000; position: absolute; top: 15%; left: 8%;}



#first-page {background-color: #ffffff;  position: relative; background-size: cover; padding-bottom: 48%;}

.header {font-size: 65px; position: absolute; top: 36%; left: 36%; color: #000000; }

.subheader {font-size: 40px; position: absolute; top: 46%; left: 35.5%; color: #a5a5a5;}

#nav-button{display:block; border-radius: 25px; width: 95px; height: 30px; background-color: #a5a5a5; position: absolute; top: 96%; left: 48%; opacity:.5;} #nav-button:hover{background-color: #a5a5a5; opacity:1.0;  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms linear; }

a:link {text-decoration:none;}



#second-page {background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: #4761fe; position:relative; top: 4%; background-size: 100%; padding-bottom: 39.5%; margin-left: -2%; margin-right: -2%;}

.Quote {font-size: 60px; color: #ffffff; position: relative; bottom: 3%; left: 2%;}

.P1 {font-size: 23px; color: #ffffff; position: relative; top: 50%; left: 50%;}

#nav-button2{display:block; border-radius: 25px; width: 95px; height: 30px; background-color: #ffffff; position: absolute;  top: 92%; left: 48%; opacity:.5;} #nav-button2:hover{background-color: #ffffff; opacity:1.0;  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms linear; }





#third-page {background-color: #ffffff; position:relative; backgroud-size: cover; padding-bottom: 44%;}

#nav-button3{display:block; border-radius: 25px; width: 95px; height: 30px; background-color: #a5a5a5; position: absolute; top: 305%; left: 50%; opacity:.5;} #nav-button3:hover{background-color: #a5a5a5; opacity:1.0;  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms linear; }
```

Comment: A couple of recommendations. `<a>` in the second line just cannot be there, it should be `<html>`. Every single element should be inside `<head>` or `<body>`, and these should be inside of `<html>`. I edited your code to reflect this. Besides, I recommend you to try and use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com/) to ask about html/css/javascript in stackoverflow, it makes your questions much easier to answer thus getting more and better answers.

Answer (score 0):

"But I'm having some issues getting the width of my page to fit the screen"

If I understand the issue - you're wanting your div content to completely fill the body? If so, have you tried:

```
body {margin:0;padding:0}
```

Edit: To get the first page to cover the entire window, try the following in your CSS:

```
html {height:100%; width:100%}
body {height:100%;}
```

then in your #first-page div, remove the "padding-bottom:48%", and add "min-height:100%". 
See example here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pnellesen/6hmxw/)

I believe that's what you're looking for, at least on your first page.

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to work for internet explorer, but my content is still wider than the screen in firefox, creating a horizontal scroll bar. I used overflow-x: hidden; to get rid of the scrollbar, but the space is still there for some reason...

Comment: I'm seeing identical behavior in both IE and FF. Apologies if I'm misunderstanding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add width:100% to body. That should to do it. Page height should be min-height property, set to whatever you want.

`<div id="box">`

`#box { min-height:70px; background-color:red;}`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kgx8G/)